# Alignment of Checkboxlist - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a Checkboxlist in my page as follows.

[image]

As you can see, the 2 checkboxes are aligned one below the other. Is it possible to bring the 2 on a single line? The design code for this is as follows.

```
<td>
                     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="Employer Type"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                        <td valign="middle">
                            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkEmployerType" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="E" Text="Employer"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="O" Text="OJT Provider"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:CheckBoxList>

                        </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write this

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="Employer Type"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                        <td valign="middle">
                            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkEmployerType" runat="server"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="E" Text="Employer"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="O" Text="OJT Provider"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:CheckBoxList>

                        </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set RepeatDirection property of CheckBoxList to Horizontal

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `RepeatDirection` property as following

```
RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
```

It creates `ul` and `li` for displaying item. You can define `css` rule do display as you like.